# Chrome Extension email link signin/signup with Firebase and manifest v3

Tags: firebase, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to do email link authentication for my chrome extension with Firebase. When the user clicks the sign in link in their email, the chrome-extension:// address is blocked by chrome, ending in an about:blank#blocked page.

My extension has the chrome-extension url in the web accessible resources and the content_security_policy explicitly set.

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
        "resources": ["welcome.html"],
        "matches": ["chrome-extension://[my-chrome-exension-id]/*"]
    }       
],
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

I've confirmed that the link from the users email is exactly as I'd expect before it gets blocked. I can't find any examples on the web of people doing email link auth with firebase in a vanilla js chrome extension. Any ideas as to what I might be missing?

Comment: Replace `chrome-extension://[my-chrome-exension-id]/*` with `<all_urls>`

Comment: I've got both of these in the manifest as well. 

 {
            "resources": [ "data/*", "css/*", "*.html"],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }, 
        {
            "resources": ["https://*/*" ],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        } ,

Comment: But those aren't working either.

Comment: Assuming you reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page, maybe the path to welcome.html is wrong i.e. the file is inside a folder.

Comment: Hm. I definitely reloaded the extension and I double checked the path. Neither of those worked, but I realised that I still had an add blocker enabled. I disabled that, and I was able to redirect to the page. The add blocker was the issue. I've now got a whole other Firebase error, but I'm going to call that progress.

Comment: Thanks for you help wOxxOm. You offered some pretty solid advice. Do you offer contracting or consulting services?

Comment: Okay. Now I'm really confused. With the ad blocker still disabled, I just tried to run through the process again and the link is blocked again. I'm clearly still missing something. I'm wondering if this has nothing to do with chrome and is maybe a Firebase issue behind the scenes.

Comment: It may be a bug in Chrome, there's plenty.